Problem with X-Frame-Options in PowerPages
I am trying to place an iframe on a powerpage with a reference to index.html stored in the same powerpages page by adding the file below:
PowerPage WebFile
But when I put it in an iframe I get an error "Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'." (The html file is available at the given url)
Iframe Error
I tried changing the option in Advanced Settings for X-Frame-Options, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything:
X-Frame-Options
Advanced Settings
